# Möbius transformation as composition of two reflections

Tags: complex-analysis

This was a bonus question of an assignment that was given to us two weeks ago so the question is mere interest to expand the understanding of the topic.

It was asked to prove that every elliptic Möbius transformation can be represented as the composition of two reflections (on circles/lines)
I didn't came near to solving this problem so i don't really have any information to share yet. Does anyone has an idea how to prove this?

Comment: What is an *elliptic* Mobius transformation?

Comment: @LukasKofler https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Elliptic_transforms

Comment: Since an elliptic transformation is just a hyperbolic rotation about some center, all you need to do is copy the corresponding Euclidean proof over.